# How do I change the folders indexed in Search?

Tags: windows-8

I have a bunch of PDFs that have been through an OCR process.  I don't believe they're being indexed in my existing search results.  How do I add these folders to the search indexer, and additionally tell the indexer to index the contents of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multiple step solution.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, then select **Control Panel**
2. Search for *search* and then Select *Change how Windows searches* under **Indexing Options**
   [image: search - Control Panel]
3. In the **Indexing Options** dialog, select *Modify* 
   [image: Indexing Options]
   and add any desired folders in the Indexed Locations dialog box.
   [image: Indexed Locations]
4. To ensure the contents of the file are indexed, click *Advanced* in the Indexing Options dialog.  Click on the *File Types* tab and ensure the pdf extension is checked and the *Index Properties and File Contents* radio option is selected.
   [image: Advanced Options]
5. In my example, the Filter Description reports "Registered IFilter is not found".  I downloaded and installed the [Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025) from Adobe.
6. Now the Filter Description reports "PDF Filter".
   [image: Advanced Options with Filter].

Comment: If you don't use Adobe's Reader, there are 3rd party PDF iFilters available as well, such as [this one](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/) from Foxit.

Answer (score 2):

Just press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> from the desktop and type `index`.

[image]

now select the option `Indexing Options`  a windows will appear and select the `Advanced` option from there, now another pop window will appear and select the tab `File type`. Now search the `.pdf` file and select it and select the option `Index properties and File content` and press Ok button.

[image]

Comment: Which is, incidentally, exactly the same process as on Windows 7 or Vista. Unsurprisingly, I might add.

Comment: @Joey go ahead.

Comment: Thanks avirk.  @Joey, it's nice to see some things haven't changed w/ the new OS.  :-D

Comment: Well, they only have so many resources so changing things that work *and* are only used by a very small minority of users *and* not even on a regular basis isn't so high on their list; after all, there are costs :-). Cf. the font installation dialog which remained unchanged from Windows 3 up to Vista, I think :-)